# Is Stack Overflow a Customer Care center in Low traffic tags?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, duplicate-answers

*Low traffic* tags are as much important as *High traffic* ones, yet, they get minimal attention from the community. Having such tags unattended will result in many "off-topic" posts. What should the community do to reduce "off-topic" posts in *Low traffic* tags?

The below is an example of a 100% duplicate answer, but the answerer ignored the rules by claiming that his "priority is IBM customer".

Has Stack-Overflow become a ["customer care center"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059262/issue-with-single-page-model-navigation/25060136?noredirect=1#comment38985612_25060136)?

In case the comment is removed or modified:

> "My experience with duplicates is that moderation tends to never reach those, so in order for the person to get a full appreciation of the subject matter, it is better to reply even if duplicate. Change how SO works, I'll gladly mark as duplicate. **My first priority is for the IBM customer.**"

To answer some of below comments:

SO is "**for professionals and enthusiast programmers**". I couldn't find help desk or help center.

Even if he works for IBM, adding the same answer over and over instead of closing it as duplicate, neglecting community rules.

Comment: I think you should define what you mean by customer care center, and point out what the implications you think that has.

Comment: @Omar what discussion are you trying to have? Or is this a rhetorical question / rant?

Comment: It's no secret that companies have employees check SO to support their products. As long as they remain on topic, does it matter?

Comment: He works for IBM Worklight, it's no surprise that he's answered a lot of relevant questions... he doesn't seem like a rep whore to me, just some guy doing his job

Comment: @0x7fffffff according to his profile, he's a developer for IBM.  I'd lean towards he is supporting the people that effectively pay his paycheck.

Comment: @psubsee2003 and eddie_cat Fair enough.

Comment: I'm more interested in his explanation of what "moderation tends to never reach those" means. I'm having trouble parsing that specific phrase.

Comment: @0x7fffffff - That's a bit harsh, don't you think? I know what I've written in answers, so I know when I've left an explanation I'm proud of. He's merely pointing back to older answers of his to similar questions, and then providing additional explanation on top of that.

Comment: @BradLarson Well, first off, it's not *additional* context.  It's not any context specific to the question.  The text not in the links is just quoting the text in those links, not adding to them.  All he's done is posted links to duplicate questions as an answer instead of voting to close as a duplicate *without adding any additional information or context specific to the question*.

Comment: @BradLarson Perhaps that could have been worded better. And I'm inclined to agree with 1 or 2 links, but 5 makes me raise an eyebrow. That's all I was really trying to say.

Comment: You edited the question and entirely changed the meaning. OP said multi-paged model, you edited entire question to single page model. Hence invalidating the current answer.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion He did comment on it though.  According to the comment there really is no such thing as a multi-paged model, and that he's simply using the wrong term for the function behavior he described.  Of course, with zero domain knowledge I couldn't say if that assertion is correct or not.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion ppl mix between single and multi, the OP uses single page model.

Comment: @Servy The [preceeding comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059262/issue-with-single-page-model-navigation/25060136?noredirect=1#comment38983217_25059262) says to search for "worklight+multipage", which yields lots of posts on SO on that concept, I found the forced editing uncalled for.

Comment: @Omar The current answer did get invalidated. The answer says - "In all of them, the idea is that Worklight is a Single Page Application.". Is this valid any longer??

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Yes, it is valid.  The statement is asserting that *the platform* is a single page application, not that the OP's code is a single page application.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion [single page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/pages-single-page/) vs [multi-page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/pages-multi-page/). The OP uses single page as per the code.

Comment: @Joe the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @eddie_cat this doesn't grant him any extra privilege over the rules set by community.

Comment: @gnat pls point me to the part that answers my question in the dup.

Comment: @Omar part that answers your question in the dup is that user breaking rules "for IBM customer" can go to hell, 'cause Stack Overflow is not a customer support for IBM

Comment: @Omar what rule did he break?

Comment: @eddie_cat posting a duplicate answer of duplicate answers.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion the dup you have proposed doesn't answer my question. The dup is discussing a case in general, while my question is specific, targeting _low traffic tags_ expert user(s). Such user(s) and tag(s) are full of duplicate/off-topic questions. Those user(s) ought to maintain their favorite tag(s) clean by not repeating themselves.

Comment: In this case, @Omar, you had the golden dupe hammer, the IBM guy didn't. The whole purpose of dupe hammer was to facilitate quick closure of dupes. **He could have only flagged, but it was you who could have closed it instantly.** You edited, commented, posted on Meta, and after a long duration, finally closed it as a dupe. He was kind of justified in saying "moderation tends to never reach those". Moderation was the most appropriate course of action, which was delayed.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion 1) I use this power wisely. 2) I needed a 2nd opinion, I got 3 instead. 3) The OP uses latest jQM version, the dup answers cover earlier version, thus, I shouldn't close a question with another that uses older version.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion  4) I have [notified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059262/issue-with-multi-page-navigation-using-jquery-mobile-framework-in-ibm-worklight/25060136#comment38985460_25060136) the answerer to update his answer since the answers he proposed are using _deprecated_ functions. The answerer has [confirmed that _deprecation_ doesn't mean removal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059262/issue-with-multi-page-navigation-using-jquery-mobile-framework-in-ibm-worklight/25060136#comment38985645_25060136), which gave me another reason to close it as dup.

Comment: Your points are valid.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, his comment is not implying he considers Stack Overflow to be a customer help centre. Rather, he is saying that *his* priority is to answer IBM-related questions. I don't have any issue with companies encouraging their staff to provide help on their products (more so, if they're disclosing it).

Secondly, he has a point about the duplicates.

One of the aspects that makes Stack Overflow a different kind of knowledge base than Wikipedia, is that it is question-driven (hence, problem-driven). Despite all the good will we want to have about having the goal of creating a repository of programming knowledge, we can't forget that: tailoring the answer and explanation to the question (and the way it's worded) is an essential part of the way Stack Overflow works. Duplicate closures can be a bit unsatisfactory in that respect, in that they barely differ from link-only answers, besides the fact they're also hosted on the site.

Comment: All he posted was a link only answer.  He *didn't* tailor the answer to the question; he *didn't* include any information specific to that user.  He just copy-pasted the first paragraph from one of his other answers and posted it below the link, without indicating that it is in fact just a quote of his other answer.

Comment: @Servy You'll find that he did provide multiple links (which you can't easily do with duplicates) and provided a summary for it all, including suggestions of what you can and can't do with it. Auto-plagiarism is a non-issue if he's selected the right parts for that question. (I was also pointing the general problem with duplicates, not necessarily for this particular Q&A.)

Comment: That "summary" is just a copy-paste of the first few paragraphs of the other answer of his.  Several of those additional links look like they should all be duplicates of a single post, as they're all containing the same content.  If some of the other posts are useful related links, they can be included in comments just fine.

Comment: I wasn't accusing him of plagiarism.  I'm fully aware that since it's his own content he doesn't need to cite himself.  My point is that it's not like it's unique content tailored to the specific question, as you're claiming, it's just a copy of the other answer; generalized statement that he included in *all* of those duplicate answers.

Comment: @Servy As a whole, the answer is an answer to that question. So yes, maybe that could be a comment instead, yet it's much more readable and useful this way, for all parties involved (including asker and other readers). This might not be the best example, but my point about the issue with duplicates remains. (I'm quite happy to close exact duplicates and I do so once in a while, but there's room for improvement in that mechanism, in general.)

Comment: The question is a duplicate, not to mention all the links are duplicates of each others.

Comment: If it's a duplicate and you closed it as a gold badge user, is a meta post required as per community rules?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion a case to be discussed, is that against community rules?

Comment: I was just pointing out some of the problems of the duplicate system. I agree the answers in this case are overall very similar, possibly too much, but that doesn't mean he didn't have a point. He didn't seem concerned so much about answered tailored to questions, rather about the fact he prefers to answer the question there and then to help, instead of having to wait (sometimes quite a while on low traffic tags) for someone to close as a duplicate. It's not ideal, but there are worse "crimes" on SO.

Comment: Actually, I had missed @InfiniteRecursion comment earlier, but you have edited the question indeed, Omar. It would seem this was not a duplicate. The fact that you can't do multi-page but have to do single-page another way (and it points to single-page solutions) certainly doesn't mean that the question was a duplicate. The fact that two questions have the same answer does not necessarily make them duplicates. The fact that the asker was misguided into trying something thinking it was multi-page but is effectively single-page does not either.

Comment: You have missed my [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267337/is-so-a-customer-care-center?noredirect=1#comment70489_267337) replying @InfiniteRecursion. Based on documentation and code given in OP, your [rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25059262/3) is _incorrect_. Trust me, I know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Omar I don't dispute the fact you know the subject, but a question that says "*I'm trying to do X with a multi-page model, but I can't get it to work, here is what I've tried + <failed attempt that looks like single-page because it's the only thing you can do anyway>*" followed by an answer that says "*You can't, you need to use single-page model like so [...]*" isn't the same as a question that says "*I'm trying to do X with a single-page model*". If the asker knew in advance they can't use a multi-page model (i.e. most of the answer), the probably wouldn't ask the question...

Comment: With your edit, anyone searching about a multi-page model in this context (however wrongly), won't find the question, and won't know it's not possible, since you've removed all references to "multi-page". The idea of indexing questions is to let others who try to do something similar find the questions, however misguided those attempts are. Corrections are for *answers*.

Comment: @Omar If the question is wrong, we shouldn't change the question. We should write an answer explaining why it is wrong. Editing isn't for correcting technical inaccuracies, as Bruno has explained. Future users who think it is multipage, will benefit from an answer explaining that it is actually single page. That is how dupes work, same question is written by different people in different ways because they _don't know the correct terms and concepts_.

Comment: @Bruno Your point is valid. After reading WL docs, it looks like both WL and jQM definition of Single and Multi are somehow the opposite. WL and jQM are both "_Single DOM Model_", however, in WL the definition of Multi-page is _unclear_. Both framework uses Ajax to load external pages into DOM rather than HTTP.